# Understanding the Projection Matrix

Tags: xna, 3d, projection-matrix

I am trying to understand what the value range of projected vectors is. It seems at odds with what MSDN says.

The code below outputs a colored triangle. The triangle is fully visible. I would expect that after the verticies have been projected, the following would be true:

X and Y are in the range of -1 to 1.
Z is in the range of 0 to 1.

I got this information from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195665.aspx

However, when I manually transform the verticies of the triangle using the product of view and projection matrix, they have the following values:

{X:1,8 Y:0 Z:3,991996}
{X:0 Y:3 Z:3,991996}
{X:-1,8 Y:0 Z:3,991996}

Why do the values fall out of the visible range, yet the trinangle is fully visible?

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace WasMachtDieProjektion
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        Matrix _view;
        Matrix _projection;
        VertexPositionColor[] _verticies;
        Vector3[] _vectors;
        BasicEffect _effect;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _vectors = new Vector3[] {
                new Vector3(-3,0,0),
                new Vector3(0,3,0),
                new Vector3(3,0,0)
            };

            _verticies = new VertexPositionColor[] {
                new VertexPositionColor(_vectors[0], Color.AliceBlue),
                new VertexPositionColor(_vectors[1], Color.Yellow),
                new VertexPositionColor(_vectors[2], Color.Red)
            };

            _effect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
            _effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

            GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = new RasterizerState() { CullMode = CullMode.None };
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            _view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -4f), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);
            _projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.01f, 20f);

            Vector3[] transformed = new Vector3[3];
            Matrix trans = _view * _projection;
            Vector3.Transform(_vectors, ref trans, transformed);

            foreach (var v in transformed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---");

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            _effect.View = _view;
            _effect.Projection = _projection;

            foreach (var pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
                GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, _verticies, 0, 1);
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying the BoundingFrustrum as proposed in the MSDN article? It should explain things a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not forget the perspective division after projection. This means after multiplying by the projection matrix, devide the transformed vector's `x`, `y` and `z` by their `w` values. So you have to work on 4D homogenous vectors instead of 3D vectors. Your initial vectors are just `(x,y,z,1)` but after the projection matrix (which is not an affine transformation) has been applied, their `w` can (and should) be `!= 1`, so you have to devide by that, which realizes the actual perspective distortion:

```
(x', y', z', w') = trans * (x, y, z, 1);
(x'', y'', z'') = (x'/w', y'/w', z'/w');
```

Consult some introductory material on 3D transformations, projections and homogenous coordinates for some more insight.

**EDIT:** I just saw another error in your code. `trans` has to be `_projection * _view`, so that `_view` gets applied first, when multiplying a vector by `trans`. Except if XNA uses the mathematically incorrect convention of `row_vector * matrix`. If that's the case, your order should do it.

Comment: You are right, that did the trick. The transform method I used seems to just throw away the 4th component. Regarding your edit, XNA indeed uses row_vector * matrix.

Comment: There's no "mathematical correct order", it's all just about convention. In the case if you transpose everything and do things left to right the outcome will be the same.

Comment: @datenwolf Yes I know in practice there's no difference. But I grew up with column vectors in my math courses. A row vector is actually a transposed vector: Mv = (vTMT)T (I see the irony in using row vectors in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think it might be because it is a projection view that no matter what the matrix is it will always represent it. If it were an orthogonal view it would then begin to not display the full triangle.