# Geometry shader calculated lines disappear on camera move

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry-shader

I draw vertex normals using geometry shader. Everything shows up as expected except that when I move the camera some lines partially disappear. First, I thought this was due to the frustrum size but I have other objects in the scene bigger than this one drawn just fine.

[Before movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIret.png)

[After movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBI3r.png)

If anyone could give me any pointer how to get rid of this effect of line disappearing, I would really appreciate it.

**Below is the code of my geometry shader**

```
#version 330 core


layout (triangles) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 6) out;

in Data{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 t_position;
    vec4 normal;
    vec2 texCoord;
    vec4 color;
    mat4 mvp;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 mv;
} received[];


out Data{
   vec4 color;
   vec2 uv;
   vec4 normal;
   vec2 texCoord;
   mat4 view;
} gdata;


const float MAGNITUDE = 1.5f;

void GenerateLine(int index) {
    const vec4 green = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    const vec4 blue = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gl_Position = received[index].t_position;
    //gdata.color = received[index].color;
    gdata.color = green;
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = received[index].t_position + received[index].normal * MAGNITUDE;
    //gdata.color = received[index].color;
    gdata.color = blue;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}

void main() {
    GenerateLine(0); // First vertex normal
    GenerateLine(1); // Second vertex normal
    GenerateLine(2); // Third vertex normal
}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330


layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 Normal;

out Data{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 t_position;
    vec4 normal;
    vec2 texCoord;
    vec4 color;
    mat4 mvp;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 mv;
} vdata;

//MVP
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main() {
    vdata.position = vec4(Position, 1.0f);
    vdata.normal = view * model * vec4(Normal, 0.0);
    vdata.texCoord = TexCoord;

    vdata.view = view;

    vec4 modelColor = vec4(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    vdata.color = modelColor;

    vdata.mvp = projection * view * model;
    vdata.mv = view * model;
    vdata.t_position = vdata.mvp * vdata.position;

    gl_Position = vdata.t_position;
};
```

Comment: Definitely looks like depth buffer clipping.

Comment: I am new to the OpenGL. How would you suggest to fix it?

Comment: @Illia You probably need to add a Projection Matrix in the Vertex Shader, as it looks like you're lacking one right now.

Comment: @Xirema Thank you for you comment but I do have proj matrix in my Vertex shader. I just added the code my vertex shader. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: @Illia: Why are you outputting *matrices* from your vertex shader? Why not just make them *uniforms* that the GS can access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the answer by Illia May 18 '16 at 22:53

> I originally had my m_zNear equal to 0.1 but when switched it to 1.0, the lines stopped disappearing. I am not completely sure why is that. If any one knows please share it

The disappearing line is about depth buffer clipping. The vertex is [projected](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) (multiplied with MV**P**-matrix) and then the vertex position is changed AFTER the projection in geometry shader (GS). These changes in GS causes the z-value to fall outside [normalized device coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269686/why-do-we-need-perspective-division) (NDC) in perspective division. With a larger `zNear` value the projected z-value is smaller so it does not fall outside NDC. Though if the value of `MAGNITUDE` in GS was large enough the lines would be clipped anyway even with a larger `zNear`. One option to fix this is to do projection in GS.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into this issue the solution is the following:

```
glm::perspective(45.0f, m_aspectRatio, m_zNear, m_zFar);
```

I originally had my m_zNear equal to 0.1 but when switched it to 1.0, the lines stopped disappearing. I am not completely sure why is that. If any one knows please share it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to google zFar zNear? [Here you go](http://bfy.tw/5puO).

Or at least trying to google that miraculous helping glm::perspective(...) function?